# Angular ui grid is filtering by string when columnDefs has field as type number. Why?

Tags: angularjs, django, user-interface, grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm using django 1.8, and angularjs 1.3.14, and jquery 1.11.0.

This is in the Controller/gridOptions/columnDefs.

```
{ field: 'credit_amt',                
  displayName: 'Credit Amount',           
  type: 'number', 
  width: '8%',   
  enableFocusedCellEdit: true, 
  visible:true,
  //This 'filters' is the sort box to do the search.
  filters: [{   
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
            placeholder: 'greater than'
          }
```

Notice that 'type' is a number. When I run this the program treats this field as a String and not a number.  So the sort doesn't work the way I need it to.
I've tried leaving out 'type' and having it auto detect the data type.  -didn't work.

Here's what the sort looks like before and after use:

[image: Before adding search items]

[image: Simply adding a 6 to the search field]

As you can see, items were filtered when none of the data was smaller than 6.
Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your own condition function

```
condition: function(term, value, row, column){
   if(!term) return true;
   return parseFloat(value) > parseFloat(term);
}
```

Comment: The issue is filtering.  I set 'type: 'number'' and tried numberStr.  Neither work.  The column is still filtered by string values and not numbers.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I implemented and it worked.  I didn't need to include 'row' or 'column'.  And it works with or without the 'if' statement.  If you don't mind, what does the if statement do?

Comment: I thought if term is null, the parseFloat will throw an exception. But it seems it does not. So I think you can remove the if statement.

Comment: The if statement turned out to be very important.  If something is added to the filter, then deleted, the search term becomes null or undefined.  Making the filter no longer work.  So //     if (!term) term = '0';     // turned out to be a very important field so set the value if the user added then removed data from the filter input.

Answer (score 1):

What version of angular-ui-grid are you using. I just made a plnkr with the similar data with sorting and filtering and it worked ok. So it could be a version issue on your end.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
  $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering:true,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'credit_amount',                
  displayName: 'Credit Amount',           
  type: 'number', 
  enableFocusedCellEdit: true, 
  visible:true,
  //This 'filters' is the sort box to do the search.
  filters: [{   
            condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
            placeholder: 'greater than'
          }
    ]

      }]
  };

 $scope.gridOptions1.data = [{
   credit_amount:1000.02
 },{
   credit_amount:1001.0
 },{
   credit_amount:100.0
 },{
   credit_amount:500.0
 }]
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQK1obRbctCUhUDrdoY2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding on @Qi Tang's answer in case there is someone like me that was looking for an answer where the filtered results only equal the filter value (not greater).

```
condition: function (term, value, row, column) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof (term) || null === term)
        return true;
    try {
        return parseFloat(value) === parseFloat(term);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.warn(ex);
    }
}
```

Note for other implemenations as well:

```
if(!term) return true;
```

will return true for **any** falsy value, make sure that is what you want. That includes not just null and undefined, but false and **0,** which in a numeric filter may not be desirable (I couldn't filter where items are 0).